# how to find the max in a datacolumn of datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime, max, datacolumn

I have a DataColumn of DateTime, I would like to know how I can have only the sooner date (min) and the later date (max).

Thanks

Comment: Just a DataColumn? Is it bound to a DataTable or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would give what you are looking for:

```
// Initial Code for Testing
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Dates", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) });
```

This is the code you would use:

```
// Actual Code
DataColumn col = dt.Columns[0]; // Call this the one you have

DataTable tbl = col.Table;

var first = tbl.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(cols => cols.Field<DateTime>(col.ColumnName))
               .OrderBy(p => p.Ticks)
               .FirstOrDefault();

var last = tbl.AsEnumerable()
              .Select(cols => cols.Field<DateTime>(col.ColumnName))
              .OrderByDescending(p => p.Ticks)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: your approach is looks best :)

Answer (score 17):

```
object maxDate = dataTable.Compute("MAX(TheDateColumnName)", null);
object minDate = dataTable.Compute("MIN(TheDateColumnName)", null);
```

Comment: Not sure this is working for dates. This is telling me that 4/1/2022 is greater than 3/1/2023.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer from kyle, isn't it easier to just do:

for greatest date:

```
var last = tbl.AsEnumerable()
               .Max(r => r.Field<DateTime>(col.ColumnName));
```

and for earliestdate:

```
var first = tbl.AsEnumerable()
               .Min(r => r.Field<DateTime>(col.ColumnName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just retreive a List of DateTime from your DataColumn,
Foreach row in your DataColumn add the current element to your List of DateTime.

`List<DateTime>` and use `Sort` method then get the first and the last values.

Depending of your framework version, for `2.0` use above, for `>=3.5`
you can use `Max` and `Min`
or
With linq  `.OrderByDesc(p => p.X).FirstOrDefault();` on your DateTime List

Comment: Once you have the List<> you might as well use Max() and Min(). But I think this is about getting the list.

Comment: @Henk, Where do you find those method? Max() and Min().

Comment: @ChristopheDebove you need to use Linq (using System.Linq)

Comment: @Henk, Dave,  yes I saw, my IDE was configured with 2.0 for my test.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyDataTable");
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("DateColumn");
dc.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
    newRow[0] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

DateTime maxDate =  
    Convert.ToDateTime(
                        ((from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                          orderby Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateColumn"]) descending
                          select dr).FirstOrDefault()["DateColumn"]
                          )
                        );

DateTime minDate = 
    Convert.ToDateTime(
                        ((from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                          orderby Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateColumn"]) ascending
                          select dr).FirstOrDefault()["DateColumn"]
                          )
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest for me:
make a dataset with a Table "Tablename" and a column "itemDate" ,set Datatyp System.DateTime

you can read all elements in a list of datetime and search for minDate

```
Dim List_Date As New List(Of DateTime)
Dim minDate As DateTime

For Each elem As DataRow In DataSet1.Tables("Tablename").Rows
            List_Date.Add(elem.Item("itemDate"))
Next

minDate = List_Date.Min
```